# Youtube embed does not fill the screen when pressing the fullscreen button

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, embed

When pressing the fullscreen button on any embedded youtube video Chrome & IE (strangely Opera webkit works fine) acts as though I have pressed F11.

http://www.babymetalfan.com/discography/babymetal-2014/01-babymetal-death/

I have tried adjusting z-index values but no luck so far.

Edit: I fixed the video here by forcing the embed to use the flash player: http://www.babymetalfan.com/2014/07/08/babymetal-the-forum-london-7-7-14-ii-ne-proshot-video/ The issue still exists on all my html5 embeds.

Comment: Look here, maybe a solution with a `<noscript>` tag (last message on the page) https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-creators/onrU2bxgaK0

Comment: I didn't find the issue but found a workaround by forcing the embed to use flash by using the old youtube embed code.

Comment: The problem with the html5 video certainly comes from a conflict with another css rule. If you have time disable all your css rules and add them back progressively to see which one is in conflict.

Comment: Fixed it! For some reason the theme's css had iframe max-width & max-height values. Changed them to 100% and now it works.

Comment: That was the key.  For me it was the `div` that contained the `iframe` that had a `max-width` set.

Comment: babymetal \v/<^-^>\v/